# How to get response from custom api to jade file in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, express, pug

I have a problem using Nodejs 
What I would like to do is as following. I have an API where I send a request to. When I get a response from the API I would like to send it to my index.jade file. I already get a response from my API but only in a console. Not in my html file (index.jade).

The code as following:

app.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
var postData = '{'+
    ' "limit": "10",'+
    ' "page": 1,'+
    ' "filters": {'+
    ' "genre": [],'+
    ' "region": "",'+
    '"prices": 2,'+
    ' "distance": 31,'+
    ' "longitude": "4.646219",'+
    ' "latitude": "52.387388",'+
    ' "eves": 1,'+
    '"from_date": "17-12-2015",'+
    '"end_date": "18-12-2014"'+

    '}'+
    '}';



var options = {
    hostname: 'API url',
    path: 'api path',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': postData.length,

    }
};

var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', (chunks) => {
     console.log(`BODY: ${chunks}`);
        var response = JSON.parse(chunks)
        res.render('index',{
        value: response
        });
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.')
    })
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
            body += chunk;


        });

        res.on('end', function(){
            var response = JSON.parse(body)
           console.log(response)
            console.log("Successful")

        });
```

index.jade

```
   p #{value}
```

Note: I'm very new to node js.

Comment: with index.jade file, you put the same folder with app.js file???

Because I see your code: res.render('index',{
        value: response
        });

Comment: no I did not do that  does de code insinuate that.

Comment: What I see in the code is that that is not the problem because I also send a title with it and that is shown on the right page. It could be that it is in a wrong function

Comment: Can you show response variable ( "var response = JSON.parse(chunks);" => "console.log(response);" ) before you render to index.jade file?

Comment: Do you mean that is shown in the console?

Comment: Ah, can you show response result before render to index.jade file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105259/discussion-between-rahul-s-and-dinhnc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I catch you correctly, please try to change your codes as below. I found there are same `req` and `res` variables in different callback functions, it will bring confuse here...

So I think maybe the same variable name cause your issue, just change one of `res` to `resp` to distinguish them, maybe it could help you.

```
var req = http.request(options, (resp) => {
    var buffer = "";

    console.log(`STATUS: ${resp.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(resp.headers)}`);
    resp.setEncoding('utf8');

    resp.on('data', (chunks) => {
     console.log(`BODY: ${chunks}`);
        buffer += chunks; // accumulate data here
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
        res.render('index',{   // send the data received to client
           value: buffer  // maybe need to JSON.parse(buffer)?
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: With this code I get a result in index.jade (when I replace JSON.parse(chuck) to chunks ) But there is only 1 result in index.jade and it should give me more results

Comment: What I also see is when I refresh it multiple times is give's me some more result but when i refresh it fast it gives me less result. so I think i'm not waiting long enough for the result from the api is there a way to solve that ?

Comment: @rahuls, If I got you correctly, please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: yes it works correctly . The only thing I'm left with is the `JSON.parse` part because when I parse the value it returns `<[object Object]>` to my index.jade (only once )

Comment: @rahuls, maybe you should debug your data received. IMHO, it could be another issue.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else but thx for your help !